# How to pass python callback to c# function call

Tags: c#, python, callback, mono, python.net

I am trying to use C# classes from python, using python.net on mono / ubuntu.

So far I managed to do a simple function call with one argument work. What I am now trying to do is pass a python callback to the C# function call.

I tried the following variations below, none worked. Can someone show how to make that work?

```
// C# - testlib.cs
class MC {
    public double method1(int n) {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing method1" );
        /* .. */
    }

    public double method2(Delegate f) {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing method2" );
        /* ... do f() at some point ... */
        /* also tried f.DynamicInvoke() */
        Console.WriteLine("Done executing method2" );
    }
}
```

Python script

```
import testlib, System
mc = testlib.MC()
mc.method1(10) # that works

def f():
    print "Executing f"

mc.method2(f)  
# does not know of method2 with that signature, fair enough...

# is this the right way to turn it into a callback?
f2 = System.AssemblyLoad(f) 
# no error message, but f does not seem to be invoked
mc.method2(f2)
```

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `mc.method2(f)`?

Answer (score 7):

Try to pass `Action` or `Func` instead of just raw function:

I used IronPython here (because right now I don't have mono installed on any of my machines but according of Python.NET [documentation](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html)  I think it should work
Actually your code is almost ok but you need to import `Action` or `Func` delegate depends on what you need.

python code:

```
import clr
from types import *
from System import Action
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"YourPath\TestLib.dll")
import TestLib
print("Hello")
mc = TestLib.MC()
print(mc.method1(10))

def f(fakeparam):
    print "exec f" 

mc.method2(Action[int](f))
```

This is a  console output:

```
Hello
Executing method1
42.0
Executing method2
exec f
Done executing method2
```

C# code:

```
using System;


namespace TestLib
{
    public class MC
    {
        public double method1(int n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing method1");
            return 42.0;
            /* .. */
        }

        public double method2(Delegate f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing method2");
            object[] paramToPass = new object[1];
            paramToPass[0] = new int();
            f.DynamicInvoke(paramToPass);
            Console.WriteLine("Done executing method2");
            return 24.0;

        }
    }
}
```

I read docs for Python.net [Using Generics](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#generics) again and also found this [Python.NET Naming and resolution of generic types](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2006-April/000472.html) look like you need to specify parameter type explicitly

[quote from there](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2006-April/000472.html):

> a (reflected) generic type definition (if there exists a generic type
>   definition with the
>       given base name, and no non-generic type with that name). This generic type
>       definition can be bound into a closed generic type using the [] syntax. Trying to
>       instantiate a generic type def using () raises a TypeError.

Comment: Thx for unfortunately just doing  `f2 = Action(f)` returns `TypeError: cannot instantiate an open generic type`. And importing Func from System doesn't work at all.

Comment: I read docs for Python.net [Using Generics] (http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#generics) again and also found this [Python.NET Naming and resolution of generic types](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2006-April/000472.html) look like you need to specify parameter type explicitly. I made a change to my answer

Comment: I finished edits to the answer please let me know if you'll have any issues

Comment: Thx! This works fine. My only issue is that I really need a Func, because my C# method needs to use the return value of the python func. When I do `var g=f.DynamicInvoke(paramsToPass)` the g seems empty. I guess this is a separate problem though. However I will award the bounty!

Comment: Thanks! I think in that case try to replace `Action` with `Func` like Func[int,int]. I'll also try to look into it a little bit later

Comment: The issue is that `from System import Func` returns an error so I can't even do what you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you should define your Delegate explicitly:

```
class MC {
    // Define a delegate type
    public delegate void Callback();

    public double method2(Callback f) {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing method2" );
        /* ... do f() at some point ... */
        /* also tried f.DynamicInvoke() */
        Console.WriteLine("Done executing method2" );
    }
}
```

Then from the Python code (this is a rough guess based from the [docs](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#delegates)):

```
def f():
    print "Executing f"

# instantiate a delegate
f2 = testlib.MC.Callback(f)

# use it
mc.method2(f2)
```

Comment: I don't really get your answer. The first line in the c# class does not make sense. Then you add 'Callback f' as an argument, when Callback is a field, not a type? Finally you try to set Callback by calling testlib.MC.Callback as if it were a fn. None of these work.

What I did try is to create a delegate member, and set it via a member fn, but that did not work. Clearly f, as it is, is not recognized as a delegate when passed to c#

Comment: Sorry, didn't run my c# code and I've never used Python.net, but I think there is a problem the way you define your callback. I fixed the first line in my example which is actually defining a delegate type (and not a field). That can be exposed to your python program using the `testlib.MC.Callback`. This is based on the example in the docs which suggests you instantiate an instance of the EventHandler/Delegate type (in the docs example, it's an event handler of type `AssemblyLoadEventHandler`).

Comment: Thx FWIW I tried a Func<double,double> instead of delegate but then I am running into errors of missing System.Func... will need to continue experimenting

Comment: btw have you tried IronPython or you stuck with Python.NET? Also check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958623/assigning-an-ironpython-method-to-a-c-sharp-delegate

Comment: I could try ironpython but I am using ubuntu and it doesn't look straightforward. I can give it a try.

Comment: It worked! I use SuSE Linux 43.3, mono 4.6.1, python 3.4, pythonnew 2.3.0. Some related caveats: I had to use clr.FindAssebmly() and clr.AddReference(), otherwise python would not import anything (warning: the file paths must not contain symbolic links). I also had to encapsulate the classes in a namespace, and then import the namespace. The classes and methods must be declared public, using the public keyword.