# python3 pythonnet generic delegates

Tags: c#, python, generics, callback, python.net

I have 64bit CPython 3.4 installation on windows7. I use the pythonnet package (2.0.0.dev1).
I want to instantiate the action delegate, but it gives me an error.

```
def display(num):
     print("num=", num)

import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
import System

paction=System.Action[System.Int32](display)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 paction=System.Action[System.Int32](display)
>   TypeError: unsubscriptable object

I guess this is the way one shall specify generics.

I have checked the docu and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384783/how-to-pass-python-callback-to-c-sharp-function-call) post, and still do not see the problem.
I also palyed around a bit with the Overload method, but did not help either:

```
paction=System.Action.Overloads[System.Int32](display)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 paction=System.Action.Overloads[System.Int32](display)
>   TypeError: No match found for constructor signature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `System.Action` (without arguments and thus not a generic) is shadowing `System.Action<T>` while `System.Func` maps directly to `System.Func<T>`. I guess this is because `System.Func` will *always* have a generic parameter and there seems to be an overload implementation in place for generics.

The generic's name in Python.NET is `` Action`1 `` (in general: `` Action`N `` with `N` being the number of generic arguments). You can get the wrapper object by using `getattr` on the module:

```
Action = getattr(System, "Action`1")
action = Action[Int32](display)
```

Comment: Ok, this seems a more legit method. I didn't knew the generics are handled this way in Python.net as it just worked in IronPython. @user2281723 you should accept this solution over mine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing this problem. I created a work around to use Actions in Python.Net

Create a .net class library project with the following code:

```
using System;

namespace PythonHelper
{
    public class Generics
    {

        public static Action<T1, T2> GetAction<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, object> method)
        {
            return (a, b) => method(a,b);
        }

    }
}
```

Compile this to a dll file and include it in your Python.net project (`clr.AddReference('PythonHelper')`)

Now in your Python.net project you can create generics with following code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('PythonHelper')
import System
from System import DateTime, Func
from PythonHelper import Generics

def myCallback(a,b):
    print a, b

func = Func[DateTime, DateTime, System.Object](myCallback)
action = Generics.GetAction[DateTime, DateTime](func)
```

If you need to create an action with more or less params, you have to add another GetAction method yourself.

Comment: Seems to be a reasonable solution. I wonder if Func works, why did they neglect the Action. Thank you!

Comment: Because this is open-source project and pull requests are welcome!